# java.io.FileNotFoundException - Can't read my properties file

Tags: eclipse, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

Eclipse/Linux - Java Web Application.

I added a file named dao.properties to my project. I put it in a package : com.cdp.dao . My class which uses this file is in the same package. 
When I try to load it I have a

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException 
/myproject/src/com/cdp/dao/dao.properties (No such file or directory) OR 
dao.properties (No such file or directory)
```

This my code :

```
Properties prop;
FileInputStream fis;
File file = new File("/myproject/src/com/cdp/dao/dao.properties");
//File file = new File("dao.properties"); doesn't work either
try {

    prop    = new Properties();
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    prop.load(fis);         
    dbUrl   = prop.getProperty("dbUrl");
    user    = prop.getProperty("user");
    pwd     = prop.getProperty("pwd");
    driver  = prop.getProperty("driver");
    fis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: just use com/cdp/dao/dao.properties inside File constructor..and let me know

Comment: It didn't work. It works when I mention the absolute pathname. Guess I didn't understand what string path the constructor excepted. it's OK now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("dao.properties");
```

to load the properties file

Answer (score 0):

From Class, the path is relative to the package of the class unless

you include a leading slash, so if you don't want to use the current package,

include a slash like this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dir/SomeTextFile.txt");
```

but if you need to use classpath use just filename like below

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("dao.properties");
```

Comment: The second solution is the right one to me. I thought the File or FileInputStream constructors used relative path. Thanks.